# UItableView section index list repositions with searchDisplayController awkwardly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, keyboard, uisearchdisplaycontroller

So currently when my searchDisplayController becomes active my section index list positions itself and changes its length in weird ways.

When I first enter a letter into the search bar this is what it looks like.
[image]
When I keep on entering characters into the search bar it looks like this.

[image]

Then, when I dismiss the key board the section index list moves down with the keyboard and looks like this.
[image]

I have set up an `NSNotificationCenter` `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` observer and tried doing `searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()` and
`searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.setNeedsDisplay()` in the selector function and it does not fix or even change anything.

This issues happens in both portrait and landscape but fixes itself upon device orientation change.

Any ideas in how to fix this or just a simple point in the right direction would be much appreciated :)

EDIT:

So, the first screen shot is what it is supposed to look like and it allows me to scroll the tableView with the keyboard up. When I dismiss the keyBoard it aligns up correctly. However after a put in a second character into the search it changes to screenshot #2 which does not allow me to use the section index list to scroll through the tableView.

Comment: Have you tried calling `reloadIndexTitlesForTableView` on its own? Should be getting done by reloadData() but worth a shot.

Comment: Just tried it and did nothing.

Comment: Not sure how your search works, but should you be returning the list of titles for the reduced sections using `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`. So only be returning A, D , M, P , V. Perhaps its showing A-Z but aligning for only 5 sections?

Comment: The side scroller should always show A-Z. So when I put the first character in, it always looks like my first screenshot (which is how it is supposed to look like with the keyboard up). If i put a second character in even if the number of sections and rows are the same the section index list on the side still changes to screenshot #2. Just tested it out.